# got or has got?

Tags: grammar, difference

if I want to say that my friend has beautiful eyes should I say

> "she has got beautiful eyes"

I would shorten the "she has" into "she's" so it would be **"she's got beautiful eyes"**

or

> she has beautiful eyes.

and the same with **"I got your back**" or **"I've got your back"**

Comment: Don't use swear words (unless you are asking about swear words)

Answer (score 1):

In the UK we'd generally say, **She's got beautiful eyes**, though we do sometimes say, **She has beautiful eyes**. In the US I *think* the situation is reversed: there is a slight UK/US divergence in the use of *got*.

We would only say, **She has got beautiful eyes** if we were agreeing with someone or contradicting someone and in either situation we would emphasize the *has*.

As **I've got your back** is a fairly recent arrival in the UK, the abbreviated **I got your back** might be avoided for fear of it being misheard as "I got you back".

Answer (score 0):

"She has got..." and "She has..." mean the same. The first is more casual, the second is more formal, but you will hear both being used.

"I've got your back" is an idiom, meaning "I'll support you". This idiom can't be changed to "I have your back" (which would just mean "I own your back.)

It is possible to use the past tense here, but it sounds even more casual. It is possible that you will sometimes hear "I got your back" used idiomatically (an meaning I'll support you).

Comment: yes I know "she's" means "she has" but should I use  "she has got beautiful eyes" OR "she has beautiful eyes"

Comment: yes, but I don't think you got my point there. I don't know which of these following sentences is correct 1. "I got your back" or 2. "I've got your back".       Do I need to add the HAVE-word?? And for the eyes thing the same thing, do I need to add the GOT-word?

Comment: _Have got_ for _have_ is very common in informal speech in British English, but frowned on in correct speech (as James says above). So, if you are having a casual conversation with a friend, it's fine to say "She's got beautiful eyes", but you don't _need_ to use _got_.