# Difference between: Has Katy got / Does Katy have

Tags: sentence-choice

English is my second language and I am trying to help someone to pass a spoken English exam (GESE trinity) in the book they ask the question:

> Has Katy got a football?

If I would ask that question I would ask:

> Does Katy have a football?

Is there a difference between the sentences, is the way I would ask it wrong? After thinking about it I realized I don't really use "got" at all whet asking if someone has something. Another question was this:

> What have you got on your desk?

Again I would ask:

> What do you have on your desk?

What the difference here?

Comment: It looks as though GESE Trinity is  British. In British English we often use _has got_ instead of _has_ in informal speech. Your versions are perfectly correct, but a little more formal. See https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/231797/got-or-has-got

Comment: When I was growing up in Britain sixty years ago, _Do you have_ and _I don't have_ were things we heard Americans say on films and TV. We would not use them except in a habitual sense (_Do you have a Christmas tree at Christmas?_) We said _Have you got?_ and _I haven't got_; or in a more formal context _Have you?_ and _I haven't_. Things have changed somewhat so that we do say _Do you have_ and _I do have_. I think (but I'm not sure) that Americans say _Have you got_ sometimes, but it is less common there than _Do you have_. I don't think they say _Have you_ for _Do you have_.

Comment: @ColinFine - at Rosendale LCC Junior Mixed school in West Dulwich (1959-63), we were corrected if we said or wrote e.g. "I've got an apple". We had to say "I have an apple".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I don't ever remember being corrected on it, but I do remember a book which likened "got" to a weed in a garden.

Comment: There was a poster on the wall in my infants class of 'poor G' who was a disconsolate lower-case letter 'g' who was always being left behind when people went huntin', fishin', ridin', etc.