# "They have got water coming up to their knees". vs "Water comes up to their knees". Which one is more idiomatic?

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-construction, present-perfect, idiomatic-language

A native speaker is telling about the floods, how it happens, how people behave during floods, etc. and she says:

**They've got water coming up to their knees.**

I know this structure is commonly used when you want to say "you own something", but I find it interesting to see it used for description of a situation. I want to find out why they don't say a simpler version **"Water comes up to their knees."** which would mean the same.

At school, we are taught **"have or have got"** means **"to have or to own or to possess something"**. And we use it that way.

In the case of the above sentence about the floods, it is a situation. There is no possessing or owning by them. We are not talking about something(waters) that they are the owner of, such as **"They have (got) a car."**

So, the sentence **"They have got water coming up to their knees."** sounds like **"They possess/own the waters.",** whereas **"They don't own anything"**. Instead the structure **"have"** or **"have got"** seems to be used to describe a situation here, where there is nothing to be owned.

So, my question is what difference does it make to say **"They have got water coming up to their knees"**, instead of **Water comes up to their knees.**

In other words, can we say, **"have (got)"** can be used when describing a situation even if we are not referring to our ownership of something?

Comment: The aspect of "idiomacy" you *should* be asking about is the difference between *He **has** nothing to do* and *He **has got** nothing to do* (i.e. - all you're really asking about is the optional use of the word ***got*** in such contexts). It's not useful to introduce completely different constructions (***Water comes up to their knees*** in your case, ***There is nothing for him to do*** in mine) as possible alternatives.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [got or has got?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/231797/got-or-has-got)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, my question is not about difference between "have got" and "have". I know they are the same. My question is why use a structure ("have" or "have got") which is normally used to mean "to possess something" or "to own something" to tell about a situation in which you don't own anything? In my case "You don't own the water". So, why use a structure "I have (got) water coming up to my knees."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least in British English, we can say 'I've got [something happening]' to mean 'I'm in a situation where [something is happening]'.

In describing flood water getting deeper, we might say *The water's coming up their knees now*, or *They've got water coming up to their knees.*

Answer (score 1):

"I have got water coming up to my knees" is not really said in AmE. Actually, "have got" isn't used that much in AmE at all. "There's water up to my knees" or "I've got water up to my knees" is probably how you would say it. I don't know really what "is more idiomatic" means, but if you want to know what to say in this situation, I would say

- I've got water up to my knees
- There's water up to their knees
- Water comes up to my knees

Comment: Why would **Water comes up to my knees** be passive?

Comment: sorry i didnt mean to do that

Comment: Will delete my comments shortly.. Suggest you do the same.